# WooCommerce Single Product Page Picture Gallery Display problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, slider, product, gallery

WordPress 5.3.3
Theme: Maison (for architects and interior designers)
WooCommerce 4.0.1

Now I have a display problem of the product single page and the standard gallery that comes with WooCommerce.

On left hand next to the main product picture I already see a small vertical stripe of around 10px of the last picture.

```
 <div class="zoom slick-slide" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 557px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="-1"> <img src="https://URL/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/M-Serie_detail_01-1.jpg">
<img src="https://URL/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/M-Serie_detail_01-1-600x600.jpg">
<a href="https://URL/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/M-Serie_detail_01-1.jpg"
class="nickx-popup fa fa-expand" data-fancybox="product-gallery" tabindex="-1"></a> <img role="presentation" src="https://URL/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/M-Serie_detail_01-1.jpg" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -984.452px; left:-1430.05px; opacity: 0; width: 2000px; height: 2000px; border: medium none; max-width: none; max-height: none;"> </div>
```

I spent hours in trying to solve that issue...has anyone any idea? Lays the problem in the woocommerce slider or do I have to change in the theme settings?

Comment: Share the product page link, that will help someone to look into the issue

Comment: difficult, it is a running demo, that should not be published yet - I know it is hard to help this way, but hopefully someone else struggled with the same issue...